# Acrobat XI Forms - Radio Button Action on click

Tags: radio-button, adobe, acrobat

In a fillable form, I would like the two adjacent fields to become shaded (no input available) if the N/A radio button is selected.  If either the Yes or No radio button is selected, I would like the first adjacent field to take the value from the PointValue field.  How would I accomplish this?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be accomplished in various ways. One possibility would be the following, which you add to the form logic calculation script (if this is the only one, then be it), which you attach to a hidden (text) field whose sole purpose is to provide a holder for the form's calculation logic. BTW, this approach is considered best practice for a smart form, because it gives maximum control over the calculations, and creates the most efficient form.

Anyway, let's assume the group of checkboxes or radiobuttons is named "mySelect", and the field with the result/to be greyed out is named myResult. The return value of the n/a button shall be "na"

Then, you would have the following piece of code in the calculation script mentioned above:

```
if (this.getField("mySelect").value != "na") {
this.getField("myResult").readonly = false ;
this.getField("myResult").strokeColor = color.gray ;
this.getField("myResult").value = this.getField("mySelect").value.toString().replace(/Off/gim, "") ;
} else {
this.getField("myResult").readonly = true ;
this.getField("myResult").strokeColor = color.blac, ;
this.getField("myResult").value = "" ;
}
```

And that should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. When I copy the code and replace the field names I get a syntax error on the last line - any suggestions?  Also, is there any way on this forum I can allow you to see the actual form? It is difficult to clearly explain the way it is currently set up.  Please advise.

Comment: One should always read what one wrote… the last line is wrong, of course; it should be the field myResult. I changed that in the original answer

Comment: In order to make the form available, put it to some cloud area (such as Dropbox), and post the link.